# How to disable SSL verification in APEX code while calling REST API?

Tags: apex, ssl

How to disable SSL verification in APEX code while calling REST API ?

I am getting following error :

Exception :::PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested targetLineNumber :::24

Comment: Is the server having issues with trusted certificates (you can check with openssl commands)? Did self-signed certificates help - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BVEjIAO

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible.

If the server you're trying to send a request to is under your control, then you should fix the SSL certificate chain. If the target server isn't under your control, you should alert the owner of the server that their certification chain is broken (and ask them to fix it).

Comment: is it possible to remove the remove the trust chain check by coding in APEX class like its present in java
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1533807/disable-trusted-certificate-validation

Comment: @Tushar No, and the appropriate resolution here is to fix the cert chain.